# NodeJS CouchDB Long Polling Debacle

Tags: node.js, express, couchdb, long-polling

I have a web app that is published via ExpressJS on NodeJS, of course. It uses CouchDB as it's data source. I implemented long polling to keep the app in sync at all times between all users. To accomplish this I use the following logic:

1. User logs into app and an initial long poll request is made to Node via an Express route.
2. Node in turn makes a long poll request to CouchDB.
3. When Couch is updated it responds to the request from Node.
4. Lastly Node responds to the browser.

Simple. What is happening, though, is that when I refresh the browser it freezes up on **every fifth refresh**. Huh? very wierd. But I can reproduce it over and over, even in my test environment. Every fifth refresh without fail freezes up Node and causes the app to freeze. Rebooting Node fixes the issue.

After much hair pulling I *THOUGHT* I solved it by changing this:

```
app.get('/_changes/:since*', security, routes.changes);
```

To this:

```
app.get('/_changes/:since*', security, function () { routes.changes });
```

However, after further testing this is just failing to run routes.changes. So no actual solution. Any ideas why long polling CouchDb from Node would do such a strange thing? On the fifth refresh I can have a break point in node on the first line of my routing code and it never get's hit. However, in the browser I can break on the request to node for long polling and it seems to go out. It's like Node is not accepting the connection for some reason...

Should I be approaching long polling from Node to CouchDB in a different way? I'm using feed=longpoll, should I maybe be doing feed=continuous? If I turn down the changes_timeout in couchdb to 5 seconds it doesn't get rid of the issue, but it does make it easier to cope with since the freezes only last 5 seconds tops. So this would seem to indicate that node can't handle having several outstanding requests to couch. Maybe I will try a continuous feed and see what happens.

self.getChanges = function (since) {

Browser:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "/_changes/" + since,
            type: "GET", dataType: "json", cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                try {
                    self.processChanges(data.results);
                    self.lastSeq(data.last_seq);
                    self.getChanges(self.lastSeq());
                    self.longPollErrorCount(0);
                } catch (e) {
                    self.longPollErrorCount(self.longPollErrorCount() + 1);

                    if (self.longPollErrorCount() < 10) {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            self.getChanges(self.lastSeq());
                        }, 3000);
                    } else {
                        alert("You have lost contact with the server. Please refresh your browser.");
                    }
                }

            },
            error: function (data) {
                self.longPollErrorCount(self.longPollErrorCount() + 1);

                if (self.longPollErrorCount() < 10) {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        self.getChanges(self.lastSeq());
                    }, 3000);
                } else {
                    alert("You have lost contact with the server. Please refresh your browser.");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Node:

Routing:

```
exports.changes = function (req, res) {

    var args = {};
    args.since = req.params.since;

    db.changes(args, function (err, body, headers) {

        if (err) {
            console.log("Error retrieving changes feed: "+err);
            res.send(err.status_code);
        } else {

            //send my response... code removed here
        }
    })
}
```

Database long poll calls:

```
self.changes = function (args, callback) {

    console.log("changes");

    if (args.since == 0) {
        request(self.url + '/work_orders/_changes?descending=true&limit=1', function (err, res, headers) {
            var body = JSON.parse(res.body);
            var since = body.last_seq;
            console.log("Since change: "+since);
            self.longPoll(since, callback);
        });
    } else {
        self.longPoll(args.since, callback);
    }
}

self.longPoll = function (since, callback) {

    console.log("about to request with: "+since);

    request(self.url + '/work_orders/_changes?feed=continuous&include_docs=true&since=' + since,
    function (err, res, headers) {

        console.log("finished request.")

        if (err) { console.log("Error starting long poll: "+err.reason); return; } //if err send it back

        callback(err, res.body);
    });
}
```

Comment: node can definitely handle many connections to couchdb. Can you share the code for how the connections are handled?

Comment: Updated with code. I'm wondering if I need to push my requests into an array and keep track of them? Then when new requests come in somehow just piggy back them on previously made requests? Or cancel the old requests and create new ones?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the request side. You shouldn't need to keep track of all the long polling request. I suspect the freezes comes from some heavy loop that you cannot break out of, so maybe try to search for those in your callback

Comment: I think using the request library to create a long poll to couch is somehow creating the problem. first I'm polling node, then Node runs a long poll to Couchdb. But when I change my code so that Node does not long poll couch, but instead short polls it every 5 seconds and when there are changes send a response, then it works.

Comment: I think I might try to switch to this library for future use:

Comment: oops here it is: <https://npmjs.org/package/changes>

Answer (score 0):

Socket.io will automatically fall back to long polling, and doesn't have a problem like the one you are having.  So just use that.  Also for CouchDB changes use this https://github.com/iriscouch/follow or maybe this one https://npmjs.org/package/changes like the other guy suggested.

Its very bad practice to reinvent things when we have popular modules that already do what you need.  There are currently more than 52,000 node modules on https://npmjs.org/. People make a big deal about copying and pasting code.  In my mind reinventing basic stuff is even worse than that.

I know with so many modules its hard to know about all of them, so I'm not saying you can never solve the same problem as someone else.  But take a look at npmjs.org first and also sites like http://node-modules.com/ which may give better search results.

Comment: Yes I'll be trying one of the libraries above as noted in my comments on the question. I didn't even think to look for a library specific to couchdb changes when it came to long polling. And truthfully sometimes I like to implement things as simplistically as possible just to get an idea how it works. But in the end I agree, no sense in reinventing anything. I'll give these a try.